# How to turn off 'silent' checkouts in VS2008/TFS

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, visual-sourcesafe, vcs-checkout

I am constantly noticing that I have files checked out for editing that I did not intend to. This cannot be a good thing. Can I have it prompt me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure you can.

In VS 2008, Go to Tools/Options to get the options dialog.

Select Source Control / Environment in the options tree.

Change the the Checked-in items settings to 'Prompt for check out' from Check out automatically.